# My Object is logging all at once, do I need to change my schema?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am working on a blog type site that allows me to post articles, and it also allows me to upload images separately. I want to associate the images with the posts.

I save all posts with a title and body into a Post model, then I save all images into an Image model. I am trying now to embed the Image model into the Post document.

I start by making the image schema and model, then I make the post schema and model, and add the 'imageSchema' as the last field in the post schema:

```
const imageSchema = {
  url: String,
  id: String
};

const Image = new mongoose.model("Image", imageSchema);

const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String,
  image: imageSchema
};

const Post = new mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

Then I upload an image to associate with a single post:

```
Image.create(img) // save image information in database
  .then(newImage => { Post.updateOne({_id: postId}, {image: { url: 
img.url, id: img.id }} , function(err, foundPost){
    if(!err){
      res.json(foundPost);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  }); })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I expect to see a post object with an 'images' object inside, that contains a url, and an id, and then I expect to be able to log just one value, (image.url)

In actuality, I see the images object with correct values, but a log of one single value outputs the whole image object. Trying to use the url value with ejs actually gives me an error.

I'm sure to be making a glaring error, but I have become blind to it.
Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried returning the `Post.updateOne` promise? i.e, `.then(newImage => { return Post. updateOne.....`

Comment: Well, the post document is updated correctly (I check it to verify with Robo 3T) but when I app.get a post view, a log of the post.url shows as undefined and causes an error.

Comment: I went ahead and added the return, and the remaining errors were easy enough to track down. Looks like most of them were because of a rookie mistake. I was sending a value on the .get route for posts, but misspelling it in the posts view. It's all working correctly now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look into async/await, it will make problems like this easier to read and debug.